# how to add additional Debian mirrors using simple cdd?

Tags: debian, pressed

I'm trying to build a custom bullseye debian ISO with PHP8 installed on it be default. In the config file under cfgs/<profile name>.conf I added this variable: `debian_mirror_extra="https://packages.sury.org/php/"`
When simple cdd runs I can see it looking for php8 packages but it fails saying the public key is missing:

```
ERROR: Condition 'EF0F382A1A7B6500!|E0B11894F66AEC98!|04EE7237B7D453EC!|EDA0D2388AE22BA9!|AA8E81B4331F7F50!|DCC9EFBF77E11517!|DC30D7C23CBBABEE!|648ACFD622F3D138!|4DFAB270CAA96DFA!|112695A0E562B32A!|73A4F27B8DD47936!|0E98404D386FA1D9!|A48449044AAD5C5D!|54404762BBB6E853!|605C66F00D6C9793!' not fulfilled for '<path>/tmp/mirror/lists/default-extra_bullseye_InRelease'.
Signatures in '<path>/tmp/mirror/lists/default-extra_bullseye_InRelease':
'15058500A0235D97F5D10063B188E2B695BD4743' (signed 2023-04-15): missing pubkey
Not enough signatures found for remote repository default-extra (https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye)!
```

Looking into is I found many errors like this during regular install (not simple-cdd ) that say to add the key like so: `wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` It makes sense. I just don't know how to tell simple-cdd to do the same?
This is the simple-cdd command I use:
`simple-cdd --verbose --debug --conf cfgs/<profile name>.conf --keyboard us --locale en_US.UTF-8 --force-preseed`